# web access config file in tfs 2012

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I am trying to find the file

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Access\Web\web.config for tfs 2012. I have 3 folders under

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Application Tier
1. Message Queue
2. TFSJobAgent
3. Web Services

I am trying to modify  in this file.

Where can I find this file or can I make this change in some other way?

Comment: What change are you trying to make?  Web Access was completely rewritten for 2012.

Comment: I am trying to add a server to add a server to <tfServers>. Is there another way to do this now?